# InvalidArgumentError on custom tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

As a part of [TPS July challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/tabular-playground-series-jul-2021), I was trying to implement a custom tensorflow model based on Recurrent neural networks

*Idea:* I wanted to include an RNN, which predicts values at current iteration, based the model's prediction at previous iteration. So, I implemented a custom Model, which saves output of current iteration, to be fed to the model's LSTM layer in the next Iteration.

However, if I call the model's fit method, I got the following error

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-0457da000b62> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(train_x,train_labels,epochs=100)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1098                 _r=1):
   1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1102                 context.async_wait()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    886         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    887         # stateless function.
--> 888         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    889     else:
    890       _, _, _, filtered_flat_args = \

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2941        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2942     return graph_function._call_flat(
-> 2943         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2944 
   2945   @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1917       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1918       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1919           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1920     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1921         args,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    558               inputs=args,
    559               attrs=attrs,
--> 560               ctx=ctx)
    561         else:
    562           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 32
     [[{{node lstm_model/weight_normalization_15/cond/else/_1/lstm_model/weight_normalization_15/cond/data_dep_init/moments/Squeeze}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_11775]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Is my method of utilizing the model correct? If not, what would be a better implementation of my Idea?

*My Code:*

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

train_labels = train_data[['target_carbon_monoxide','target_benzene','target_nitrogen_oxides']].copy()
train_x = train_data.drop(['target_carbon_monoxide','target_benzene','target_nitrogen_oxides','date_time'],axis=1)
train_x.head()
train_labels = np.asarray(train_labels).reshape(-1,1,3)


curroutput = tf.Variable(shape=(1,3),initial_value=[[0.0,0.0,0.0]],dtype=tf.float32)
class CompleteModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        x,y = data
#         x = tf.reshape(self.curroutput,shape=(1,1,3))
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(y_pred,y, regularization_losses=self.losses)

        global curroutput
        curroutput.assign(y_pred)
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}



class RNNInputLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RNNInputLayer,self).__init__()
    def call(self,inputs):
        global curroutput
        return tf.reshape(curroutput,shape=(1,1,3))



def make_model():
    input_layer = layers.Input(shape=8,batch_size=1)
    dense_in = tfa.layers.WeightNormalization(layers.Dense(16,activation='selu'))(input_layer)
    dense_in2 = tfa.layers.WeightNormalization(layers.Dense(32,activation='selu'))(dense_in)
    dense_out = tfa.layers.WeightNormalization(layers.Dense(8,activation='selu'))(dense_in)
    rnn_input = RNNInputLayer()(input_layer)
    lstm_layer = layers.LSTM(units=16,input_shape=(1,3))(rnn_input)
    lstm_dense = tfa.layers.WeightNormalization(layers.Dense(16,activation='selu'))(lstm_layer)
    finalconcat = layers.Concatenate()([dense_out,lstm_dense])
    final_dense = tfa.layers.WeightNormalization(layers.Dense(16,activation='selu'))(finalconcat)
    output_layer = layers.Dense(3)(final_dense)

    model = CompleteModel(inputs=input_layer,outputs=output_layer,name='lstm_model')
    return model
model = make_model()
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(),optimizer='Adam')



model.fit(train_x,train_labels,epochs=100) #error
```

Comment: What is this `input_shape=(1,3)` in this line `lstm_layer = layers.LSTM(units=16,input_shape=(1,3))(rnn_input)` ?

Comment: it means that I'm training an input of batch 1, each of which is of shape 3

Comment: the shape of dense_out layer is (batch_size, 8) but the shape of lstm_dense layer is (batch_size, 16) since you are taking only last time step I believe. So how are you concatenating dense_out and lstm_dense on axis=0? (The dimensions in axis=-1 are different)

Comment: as the batch size is set to 1, should -1 and 1 really make a difference?

Comment: Btach_size is not the point here...batch dimension is the value is dim=0 but the value in the last dimensions of dense_out and lstm_dense are not equal (because (,,8) and (,,16)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the batch size. The `fit()` function sets the batch size to 32 by default, but the batch size from the `RNNInputLayer` layer is 1, resulting in an error. The error can be fixed by adding batch size=1 to the fit() function, as shown below.

```
model.fit(train_x,train_labels,epochs=10, batch_size=1)
```

Kindly refer to this [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/85caaf2bdd895fbc7484a6a7752df99b/untitled198.ipynb) for complete code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As Priya highlighted, the error says dim[0] which refers to the batch dimension so **this answer might not solve your error but it will definitely help you ​implement your model**.

Within your `make_model()` function, try changing `dense_out` to

```
dense_out = tfa.layers.WeightNormalization(layers.Dense(8,activation='selu'))(dense_in2)
```

Within the `make_model()` function, your `dense_in2` layer is not used as the input to your `dense_output` layer. You probably wanted to use this layer in your model and forgot to add the 2 to the end of the variable name. Additionally, I would assume that the `dense_output` layer is looking for an input dimension of 32 neurons which MIGHT the the cause of the error (though this may have been bypassed completely by the way the WeightNormalization layer object is implemented).